# Regular expression on raw HTML

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting raw html from one site in javascript.

Here is the example part:

```
<a href="/?Stat=5&item=10739">Coldwater</a></b>
```

Now I use `exec` to pull some data out with pattern:

```
Stat=5&item=(\d.*)">(.*)<\/a><\/b>
```

It works fine in regex tester ([link](http://regex101.com/r/nC8dP9/1)), problem is how to write in js, currently I have this code (returns null):

```
$.get(link,function(data) {
    var raw = data,
        pattern = / Stat=5&item=(\d.*)">(.*)<\/a><\/b>/gi,
        matches = pattern.exec(raw);
    console.log(matches);
});
```

Probably I have to remove some single/double quotes, slashes from that raw html?

Comment: HTMl is a tree shaped data structure - consider loading the string into a DOM (either in the browser or JSDOM on the server depending on where your javaScript is running) and querying it using DOM methods.

Comment: Why there is a space before `S`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags But seriously, don't use regex, see what Mr_Green said. Put your data to a new element and get all `a` tag's `href`s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here there is no need to use regex. You can achieve the same by creating a new element.

```
var a = document.createElement('div'); 
a.innerHTML = yourString;
var result = a.children[0].href;
```

Comment: Since this is even better solution, I accept this answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space before the string `Stat`,

```
> var str = '<a href="/?Stat=5&item=10739">Coldwater</a></b>';
undefined
> console.log(/Stat=5&item=(\d.*)">(.*)<\/a><\/b>/gi.exec(str)[0]);
Stat=5&item=10739">Coldwater</a></b>
> console.log(/Stat=5&item=(\d.*)">(.*)<\/a><\/b>/gi.exec(str)[1]);
10739
> console.log(/Stat=5&item=(\d.*)">(.*)<\/a><\/b>/gi.exec(str)[2]);
Coldwater
```